# how to perform custom 301 redirect in cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

I have got some 404's URLs  on  the  site  that I want to  redirect to another URLs. 
For Example :

1)  https://www.gel-nails.com/opi-avojuice-skin-quenchers-berry-juicie-lotion-30ml-1oz.html   to redirect    to   this link : https://www.gel-nails.com/opi-avojuice-holly-red-hand-body-lotion-new-look.html

2)  https://www.gel-nails.com/soft-bit-medium1.html  to  redirect to this link : https://www.gel-nails.com/

So what I have done is I went to the  Website → SEO → 301 redirects
and then On the opened page clicked the + button in the right upper part of the page afterwards  filled up the Old URL field and New URL field define accordingly and selected type was - custom. Clicked Create and now I can see the New redirects  added to the list. But whenever I am checking these urls on the web browser it's  not working.

Here is the CS- CART version that I found we are using : CS-Cart 4.8.1.SP1

Answer (score 0):

Standard solution: try clearing the cache
Through the administrative panel, or better adding ?cc&ctpl to your administrative panel URL